# Unable to complete Android Studio installation in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

The installation wizard of Android Studio is unable to complete the installation process. It gives error message:

```
The following SDK component was not installed: extra-google-m2repository
```

[image]

I tried installing with root user privileges but it shows the same error. How do I complete the installation process ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you happen to try to install Android Studio using this?:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make

I haven't had any problems with that method so I would suggest using it.